# JaCoCo: missing classes directory

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, code-coverage, jacoco

I am fairly new to JaCoCo and I am having trouble generating my code coverage report.

This is my project structure:

[image]

My integration tests live within the "...-integration-tests" module. When I build my project using mvn I get the following in my logging:

```
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing classes directory: ...-integration-tests\target\classes
```

This is true because my compiled code is only available in the target>classes of the corresponding module.

What is the best way to make this working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all as you are running IT integration test, you must be running the project's app's .war behind Tomcat or similar JVM. You have to attach jacocoagent.jar and provide destfile=jacocoIT.exe or some name to your target JVM (Tomcat)'s start script or pass the Options to it. Then, it'll get the class files. Right now, it's treating your IT tests module as a project and there are no classes there. Where are you generating the class files for the IT test source code?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because JaCoCo "report" mojo is trying to find sources and classes in "default" maven project layout:

```
@Override
boolean canGenerateReportRegardingClassesDirectory() {
    return new File(getProject().getBuild().getOutputDirectory()).exists();
}
```

Having layout similar to yours I was able to circumvent JaCoCo configuration limitations by explicitly setting **build.sourceDirectory** and **build.outputDirectory** to point on internals of your tested module. After that maven tried to compile it for second time, so I've also had to **override default compile execution**, important (and shareable) part of my Tests module pom.xml now look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...
...
    <parent>
...
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
...
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
...
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>../../Source</sourceDirectory> <!-- tested sources root, in proper layout: src/main/java -->
        <outputDirectory>../bin</outputDirectory> <!-- tested classes root, in proper layout: target/classes -->

        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/../../Test/java</testSourceDirectory> <!-- if tests code also taken from outside -->

        <testResources>
            ...
        </testResources>

        <plugins>
...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- disabling default-compile -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                            <includes/>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
...
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- typical jacoco usage -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
...
                    <argLine>${argLine} -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xmx1024M</argLine>
...
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
...
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```