# How to configure jacoco for integration tests written in jersey test framework

Tags: junit, integration-testing, code-coverage, jacoco

I am trying to integrate jacoco. I successfully integrated it with unit tests using the following configuration

```
<plugin>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        <goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>report</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>report</goal>
        <goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

I replaced prepare-agent goal with prepare-agent-integration but i cant see any reports.

I see a message saying skipping jacoco execution due to missing classes directory.

My integration tests are in a seperate module.

Can anyone please help me how to configure jacoco for my integration tests?

I am using jersey-test-framework-grizzly2 1.12 from com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework. (I know this is a very old version of jersey test framework, but this is a legacy/old application)

Comment: Meanwhile i added maven copy resources plugin to copy the required class files from other module to target/classes and jacoco is now generating the report. I dont know how far this hack will work.
On the other hand the report does not show the source code.

Comment: If you're comfortable with copying stuff around, try to copy sources to src/main/java. Check this answer for more detailed question and answer, which is probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39666052/53481